# sort command not working as expected for uppercase letters followed by underscore

Tags: bash, sorting, collation, collate

I'm sorting a list of usernames. When the letters are lowercase, the sort command works as expected.

Expected and actual output for lowercase:

```
n
n_123
na
na_123
```

When the characters are uppercase and followed by an underscore, things get weird.

Expected output for uppercase:

```
N
N_123
NA
NA_123
```

Actual output for uppercase using **sort**:

```
N
NA
NA_123
N_123
```

I thought I'd be able to solve this using

```
env LC_COLLATE=C sort $file
```

but no dice.

Actual output using **env LC_COLLATE=C sort**:

```
N
NA
NA_123
N_123
```

I'm running GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0) on Mac OS X 10.12.3

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I use homebrew and my sort version is sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `env` -- `LC_COLLATE=C sort` will have the shell export `LC_COLLATE` with the value `C` only for the duration of the `sort` command as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Underscore is ASCII `95` and that comes after all the uppercase letters (`A-Z`) i.e. `65-90`. So in sorting uppercase letters will always come before `_`.

If you want to delimit at `_` then you can use `-t _` to get your expected output:

```
sort -t _ -k1,1 file
N
N_123
NA
NA_123
```

Reason why your `sort` command worked with lowercase letters is because lowercase letters come after `_` i.e. `97-122`

Comment: Great, that makes sense and it has worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.